# How to move all data from one SQL table to another

Tags: mysql

I want to move all the data from one SQL table to another, where both tables have identical structures.

**Sample Data**:

```
Table A
| ID | Name | Address|

Table B
| ID | Name | Address|
```

**Requirement** :
Move all the data from Table B to Table A, but **don't** want to use *select* on Table B and *insert* on Table A for all the data. Preferably, alter the table structures, to achieve this.

**Initial Thoughts** :
I initially deleted Table A, and renamed Table B to Table A. That worked. But the problem is that I cannot append to the data in Table A. I want to retain the data in Table A, and append the data in Table B to Table A. So, this solution didn't work.

Any pointers on how to proceed with this, will be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT** :
My apologies to all, for a stupid question. The best way to do this is to use INSERT ... SELECT... My apologies, again!

Comment: `INSERT INTO TableA SELECT * FROM TableB` --  what's the problem with this?

Comment: @Rohitesh . . . You have just said "I want to drive to the store in my car, without turning on the engine".  Why are you excluding the SQL construct that is designed for the purpose you have in mind?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to simply rename both tables in a single [MySQL RENAME TABLE statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/rename-table.html)

```
RENAME TABLE TableA to TableB, TableB to TableA
```

Should MySQL throw an error or not work correctly with the above, you could instead use a dummy name and three statements.

```
RENAME TABLE TableA to badTable;
RENAME TABLE TableB to TableA;
RENAME TABLE badTable to TableB;
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But I didn't get around trying this. The INSERT SELECT format seemed to be best option.

Comment: You may want to give it a try if you have any noticable runtime at all.  An INSERT and SELECT require touching a whole bunch of data rows.  A RENAME requires touching only a little bit.

Answer (score -1):

ı have't try this but ı think that will work

```
insert into 'Table_A' ('Name','Address') values (select 'Name','Address' from 'Table_B')
```

Comment: invalid syntax. 1.) identifier shouldn't be wrap with single quotes. 2.) there is no `VALUES` keyword in `INSERT INTO..SELECT` statement

Comment: Sorry about syntax but I don' t want to write code, I want to show a way

Comment: Showing a way and giving a code with mistakes are two different things. You can either explain things to guide, or show code, which should work - otherwise it's simply wrong...